# Display the JVM's ThreadStackSize during the execution of an application

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, stack-overflow

I need to debug an application that sometimes produces a StackOverflow exception. This only occurs sometimes, and I do not know where is the problem because the exception is thrown in a thread that is always refreshing a picture, so there is no way to see the full stack trace.

In order to reproduce the error each time I run the application (instead of need to execute it several times until the error suddenly occurs) I want to reduce the JVM's ThreadStackSize. I know how to do this, but what I would like to do is to display the current JVM's thread stack size through the console to be sure that the change is effective.

So, my question is: Does Java provide any mechanism to display the mentioned information during the execution of a specific app?

Comment: Do you ask about stack trace or about stack size? Your title contradicts with question.

Comment: Did you try -xss=128k or less? It could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> display the current JVM's thread stack size through the console

```
jinfo -flag ThreadStackSize PID
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Mission Control provides an interface to JVM internals, to stack also.
There is a official [demo](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html). All you need is to connect to JVM.

By the way: you can implement simple call tracker with counter and call sequence.